# SQL check and update table conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The company has a SQL table[Tatkal_Merge] containing multiple Branches having many Accounts.

Whenever new accounts are added to the Branch a kit will be scanned and dispatched for each account.

Whenever all the scanning for the accounts of a particular branch is completed the branch is tagged as completed with Time stamp.

> [br_complete_qc]='Y',br_complete_Qc_date=GETDATE()

Currently, we are doing the same using the below code:

```
update Tatkal_Merge set [br_complete_qc]='Y',br_complete_Qc_date=GETDATE() where act_no in (
  select act_no 
  FROM [Tatkal].[dbo].[Tatkal_Merge] 
  where [br_complete_qc]='N' and 
  data_date+br_code not in (select distinct data_date+br_code FROM [Tatkal].[dbo].[Tatkal_Merge] where pin_scan='N')
  )
```

Data Date is Nvarchar. e.g.: 2016-10-16.

Account Nummber is primary key.

Currently, the code is taking time for execution.

What is the better/correct way of achiving it?

Comment: Microsoft SQl Server 2016

Comment: Why on earth are you storing a `DATE` in a VARCHAR?

Comment: The table was already created by someone else with Date as varchar. Don't want to change the existing system. But is it the reason of slowing down the update?

Answer (score 0):

AVOID subquery, because subquery it slows EXECUTION

```
  declare @dateBrcode varchar (100)
  select distinct @dateBrcode =   data_date+br_code FROM
  [Tatkal].[dbo].     [Tatkal_Merge] where pin_scan='N'
  declare @actno varchar(100)
  select @actno =  act_no 
  FROM [Tatkal].[dbo].[Tatkal_Merge] 
  where [br_complete_qc]='N' and 
  data_date+br_code not in (@dateBrcode)

 update Tatkal_Merge set [br_complete_qc]='Y',
 br_complete_Qc_date=GETDATE()  where act_no in (@actno)
```

Comment: Once the branch is completed, all the accounts in it will be updated. Don't think it will work